# Showing $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous with sequences $|x_n-y_n| < 1/n $ for all $n \in \Bbb N$ with $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|> \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that $x^2$ defined on $\Bbb R$ is not uniformly continuous because for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists sequences $x_n, y_n \in \Bbb R$ with the property that
$|x_n-y_n| < 1/n $ for all $n \in \Bbb N$ with $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|> \epsilon$. I want to find specific sequences.

Typically in proving that $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous, I have seen the technique of allowing $\epsilon = 1$ and so there must exist a $\delta$ with $|x-y| < \delta $ implying $|f(x)-f(y)|< 1$, and then choosing any $x$, and $y=x+\delta/2$ leads to a contradiction, but I am having difficulty converting this argument into the desired argument. Hints appreciated.

Comment: Note that the derivative of $f(x) = x^2$ tends to infinity as $x$ grows.  So, for large $x,y$ that are close to each other you can estimate $|f(x) - f(y)| \approx f'(x)  |x-y|$.  So given $\epsilon$ and $n$, choose $x$ so that $f'(x)$ is sufficiently big to make $ f'(x) |x-y| > \epsilon$.  Now you can figure out how to make this idea rigorous...

Comment: $$\eqalign{
  & {x_n} = n + \frac{1}{{2n}}  \cr 
  & {y_n} = n \cr} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and choose $a_n:=2\varepsilon n$, $x_n:=a_n+\frac1{4n}$, 
$y_n:=a_n-\frac1{4n}$. Then $x_n-y_n=\frac{1}{2n}<\frac{1}{n}$ and $x_n^2-y_n^2=\frac{a_n}{n}=2\varepsilon>\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

**Goal:** (Negate the definition of uniformly continuity) We want to show that for some $\varepsilon$ then for any $\delta>0$, there exists $x,y$ so $|x-y|<\delta$ but $|f(x)-f(y)|>\varepsilon$.

**Hint:** Note that $|f(x)-f(y)|=|x^2-y^2|=|x-y| \cdot |x+y|$. This implies that no matter how small $|x-y|$ is, we can always choose $x,y$ large enough to make $|x+y|$ sufficiently large which eventually make $|f(x)-f(y)|$ big.